# Different content in odd and even pages

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm using Jasper iReports 5.2.0 and I want to print a list on odd pages of the report and a static text on the even pages.

To achieve this I created a report with my query of a list with 100 sequential rows and put it in the **Detail 1** and my static text in **Detail 2**.

Then I added:
`Print When Expression = $V{PAGE_NUMBER}%2 != 0` to **Column Header** and **Detail 1**
and `Print When Expression = $V{PAGE_NUMBER}%2 != 0` to **Detail 2**
and also maximized **Detail 2 Band** Height (without this I will loose more rows)

Everything show in the right pages but report aren't showing all rows.
I mean, if my query return 100 rows, 1-100

- 1st page show 1-20
- 2nd page show static text
- 3rd page show 22-40
- 4th page show static text
- 5th page show 42-60
- ...

What should I do so that row be printed in the right page?

Answer (score 0):

You should do the following:

Create 2 Detail Bands:

a) Detail1 - For static even pages (**!make sure this detail band is first**). Maximize it's size - to use whole page, put your static text on it. Set `PrintWhenExpression = $V{PAGE_NUMBER}%2 == 0` on band

b) Detail2 - For your data, **do not use any PrintWhenExpressions on it**

How it works: wholepage DetailBand1 is shown only on even pages, because it takes whole page, your data detail band (Detail2) is moved to even page, so everything works as expected, and no records are missed.

Comment: That was one of the other options I tried after my post and for what I was able to discover (if I remember correctly) this is the _solution_ to my question but if you need to make totals it will not been shown right.

Comment: didn't edit the comment on time for the rest of my response...

Ex:
1st Page show 3 rows with a value of 2 each, the total in this page show 4, in the 2 page (static text) will show a total of 2.

The only way I found to correctly print a report (ex.invoice report) with a static text in the back was using a main report to count the number of pages I need based on the number of rows that can fit in each page. I will explain my solution better, not enough available characters here

Comment: you're right, It might not work when you want to subtotals/totals.
One more way I'm thinking about is to create 1 Detail band.On Each of data bands (GroupHeader, Detail etc) add the _PageBreak_ element **above** text fields with `PrintWhenExpression = $V{PAGE_NUMBER}%2 == 0`. and use *Background* band for your StaticText. then set `PrintWhenExpression = $V{PAGE_NUMBER}%2 == 0` o\for BackgroundBand. Please let me know if it helps.